# Is there any way to manage severity of a trigger, created via trigger prototype in low-level discovery?

Tags: zabbix

I have a discovery rule, which has a trigger prototype. This prototype generates a set of triggers via discovery.

I need to manage these triggers severity via discovery rule (I can return desired severity of trigger as a number or string in discovery item, something like `'{#SEVERITY}' : 5`).

I've found a `{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}` macro in zabbix docs, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Is there any way to manage the severity of a generated trigger by trigger expression?

Comment: I think you could do it via multiple discovery rules, with a filter based on #severity :) you may also want to consider using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible currently. You might want to vote on this feature request: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3352 .

Comment: Thanks!

As a workaround I've just split discovery json within my application code via severity and added more discoveries, each containing trigger prototypes with desired severity.